# Show that the subgroup $\langle\tau\rangle=\{\tau^n | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is normal in $S_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Show that the subgroup $\langle\tau\rangle=\{\tau^n | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is normal in $S_3$ where $\tau \in S_3$ is the 3-cycle:

$(123) = \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\2&3&1\end{bmatrix}$.

So for $g\in S_3$, $h\in \langle\tau\rangle$,  I have to prove that $ghg^{-1}\in \langle\tau\rangle$ or equivalently $g\langle\tau\rangle g^{-1} = \langle\tau\rangle$. I have no idea how to do this. I think the inverse would be $(312)$, so I have to show $(123)*\tau^n*(312)=\tau^n$?

Comment: Do you know the fact that if G is a group with a subgroup H of index 2 in G, then H must be normal in G?

Comment: First, note that $(312)$ is just another name for $(123)$, not the inverse of it, which is $(132)$. It might speed things up if you study up on the cycle notation a little more, once you get used to it it's really convenient for calculating.

Second, note that you have the thing you need to show a little backwards. You need this to be true for every $g$, but you're putting $\tau$ in and saying that's all you need to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the inverse would be $(312)$.

No, you can check that $(123)(312) \neq 1$. In fact, $(312) = (123)$ and the square of a three-cycle cannot be the identity.

Instead, you can check that $(123)^{-1} = (132)$. (Which is also equal to $(321)$ and $(213)$).

But I'm not sure why you were trying to compute its inverse anyway.

---

> I have to show $(123)*\tau^n*(312)=\tau^n$?

No, you need to show that given any $n \in \Bbb Z$ **and $\sigma \in S_3$**, there exists $m \in \Bbb Z$ such that
$$\sigma \tau^{\color{red}{n}} \sigma^{-1} = \tau^{\color{red}{m}}.$$

Moreover, since $\tau$ generates the subgroup $\langle \tau \rangle$, it suffices this to prove for this $n = 1$ (and all $\sigma$). (Do you see why?)

Thus, you only need to show that for every $g \in S_3$,
$$g \tau g^{-1}$$
is in $\langle \tau \rangle$, i.e., is a power of $\tau$.

First note that this is clearly true if $g$ is in $\langle \tau \rangle$ as $g$ and $\tau$ commute. This takes care of three elements.

Now, suppose $\sigma \notin \langle \tau \rangle$. In this case, check that the other elements of $S_3$ are $\sigma\langle \tau \rangle = \{\sigma, \sigma \tau, \sigma \tau^2\}$.
By an argument as earlier, it suffices to prove this for $g = \sigma$ (why?).
That you can do by simply picking any $\sigma \notin \langle \tau \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The subgroup $\langle \tau\rangle = \{id, \tau,\tau^2\}$ has order 3 and so the index of this subgroup in $S_3$ is 2.

Generally, each subgroup $U$ of a group $G$ with index 2 is normal.